# Kurtosis of non standard normal distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Say if I have a X~N($\mu,\sigma^2$) 
Have I can find the kurtosis from kurtosis of standard normal distribution = 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All normal distributions can be seen as [location- and scale-adjusted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location%E2%80%93scale_family) forms of a standard normal.

Since kurtosis is unaffected by scale and location changes, the kurtosis will not change, so is $3$ for all normal distributions (and the excess kurtosis is $0$ for those who think that way)